# How to make a CAPS LOCK indicator using PYTHON on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32, capslock

i wanted to make a caps-lock and num-lock indicator using python on windows,
but i dont know how to start with and what all modules and library i need to implement my desired output.

**THE OUTPUT** i desire is that whenever i press **CAPS-LOCK** the borders of screen should go green and for *NUM-LOCK** blue.

also, does it require a **GUI?**

**(but i want it to be transparent. i don't want minimise,close and maximise buttons on gui)** and this all process should be done in background.

**Please guide me on how should i approach this.
THANKS A LOT.**

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's the WinApi package for python here.](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)

Not very well documented, but after quick look at demos looks like this code works:

```
import win32api
import win32con
print(win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_CAPITAL))
```

For green frame you'll need probably some GUI library (GTK+, Qt), but I don't know which one could achieve such effect.

Edit: I figured you can actually use the same WinApi to draw on the screen.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

pen = win32gui.CreatePen(win32con.PS_SOLID, 7, win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0))
dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
win32gui.SelectObject(dc, pen)
win32gui.MoveToEx(dc, 0, 0)
win32gui.LineTo(dc, 1920, 0)
```

Comment: I can't understand "dc=win32gui.GetDC(0)" why are we using that?

Comment: Normally you would pass there a window id to get its drawing context, but apparently the screen is special case and it's under zero id.

Comment: i would love to know what each line from 4 to end does , sorry i am new to this library and cant get a basic ideas on windows id and how to use them

Comment: HOW TO DELETE THOSE LINES AFTER DRAWING